# Custom sort of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having an array of data like this:

```php
$array = array(
'total_ids' => 0,
'unique_ips' => 0,
'unique_ids' => 0,
'global' => 0,
'total_ips' => 0,
);
```

I need it to be sorted to this:

```php
$array = array(
'unique_ids' => 0,
'unique_ips' => 0,
'total_ids' => 0,
'total_ips' => 0,
'global' => 0
);
```

I believe this can be done via uksort, but i can't find the solution of custom_sort function.

Comment: Your desired sorting order makes no sense to me. Can you elaborate? What rules does it follow?

Comment: I have a set of such arrays but not sorted. I'll be inserting the values to the database with a single query, like INSERT INTO `table` (`unique_ids`,`unique_ips`,`total_ids`,`total_ips`,`global`) VALUES (...),(...),(...) etc. Thats why i need the arrays of this set to be sorted identically.

Comment: Thank you all for fast replies! Seeing the whole question here helped me. > I need the arrays of this set to be sorted identically That means i can just sort them, for instance, alphabetically. That way they are sorted identically and I can use them in the query. Btw, the logic of sorting I wanted was really odd. I am really sorry I made you waste your time at this question.

Comment: The more info you give us the easier it will be to figure out what you're trying to achieve, everyone here is willing to help to not only solve the problem, but to help you understand why things might be better done in other ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems rather pointless, can you provide a reason why you need this? I assume it's something to do with a looped output.

```
$new_array = array(
  'unique_ids' => $array['unique_ids'],
  'unique_ips' => $array['unique_ips'],
  'total_ids' => $array['total_ids'],
  'total_ips' =>$array['total_ips'],
  'global' => $array['global']
);
$array = $new_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the sorting is done by string length, then by alphabetical ordering. That's not too hard to accomplish using [uksort](http://php.net/uksort)!

```
function cmp( $a, $b) 
{
    if( strlen( $a) != strlen( $b))
    {
        return strlen( $a) < strlen( $b) ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return strcasecmp( $a, $b);
}

uksort( $array, 'cmp');
```

**Output:**

```
// Before uksort()
array(5) {
  ["total_ids"]=>
  int(0)
  ["unique_ips"]=>
  int(0)
  ["unique_ids"]=>
  int(0)
  ["global"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_ips"]=>
  int(0)
}
// After uksort()
array(5) {
  ["unique_ids"]=>
  int(0)
  ["unique_ips"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_ids"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_ips"]=>
  int(0)
  ["global"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

[See the magic](http://codepad.org/GisGby3u).

Answer (score 0):

**This will sort the array descending based on the array key**

You want to sort the array descending so you can use this function `krsort` which will sort the array based on the key descending and I will put them in new array named sorted array

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'total_ids' => 0,
    'unique_ips' => 0,
    'unique_ids' => 0,
    'global' => 0,
    'total_ips' => 0,
    );
    krsort($array);
    $sorted_array = array(); 
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $sorted_array[$key] = $value; 
}
print_r($sorted_array); 
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't produce the OP's desired output. You don't need the foreach loop since krsort is in-place, and [the keys are mixed up](http://codepad.org/3IN9Wxfb).

Comment: Yep! That's why I couldn't use krsort :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a set of such arrays but not sorted. I'll be inserting the values to the database with a single query, like INSERT INTO table (unique_ids,unique_ips,total_ids,total_ips,global) VALUES (...),(...),(...) etc. Thats why i need the arrays of this set to be sorted identically

So why not do something like

```
$array = array(
'total_ids' => 0,
'unique_ips' => 0,
'unique_ids' => 0,
'global' => 0,
'total_ips' => 0,
);


 'INSERT INTO table(' . implode(', ', array_keys($array)) . ') VALUES (' . implode(', ', $array) . ')'
```

*Quickly typed it, expect some syntax errors.*

Comment: **set of arrays in a single query** `INSERT INTO table (unique_ids,unique_ips,total_ids,total_ips,global) VALUES ('0','0','0','0','0'),('0','0','0','0','0'),('0','0','0','0','0')...` If the won't be sorted, the values would mix up.

Comment: So just do INSERT INTO table (unique_ids,unique_ips,total_ids,total_ips,global) VALUES ($array['unique_ids'],$array['unique_ips'],$array['total_ids'],$array['total_ips'], $array['global']) It's not that hard to make a loop that adds more data to the query. I don't see what is so hard about this.